# If $X_i\sim N(0,\frac{1}{\theta})$, find $E\left(\frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 +2}\right)$

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference, bayesian, expected-value

The initial question states that the $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\frac{1}{\theta})$, where $\theta$ follows an exponential distribution with parameter equal to 1. We are asked to derive the Bayesian estimator $\hat{\theta}_n$ of $\theta$ and show it is a consistent estimator. I followed the convention by first deriving the $g(\theta|x)$, which is a Gamma$(\alpha,\beta)$ with $\alpha=\frac{n+2}{2};\beta=\frac{2}{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 +2}$.

Then I derived the expected value of $g(\theta|x)$, which is $\alpha\beta$.

I intended to show that 
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}P(|\hat{\theta}_n-\theta|\leq \epsilon)→1$$

by showing that $$E(\hat{\theta}_n-\theta)^2=0$$ when $n\to \infty$.

My first instinct is to just calculate $E(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2)$ in the denominator but I am concerned that it would be inappropriate.

Comment: I think your denominator should be $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2$.

Comment: @AdityaDua My friend and I got the same answer for $\beta$....

Comment: Why do you want to compute that expectation?

Comment: Since $\sum_{i=1}^n X^2$ is just $nX^2$, I think you missed the indices $i$ in your formulae and you are probably working with an i.i.d sample $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ of size $n$.

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand why you want to compute the expectation  $E\left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2\right)$.

If the posterior is as you said with
\begin{equation}
\alpha_n =\frac{n+2}{2};\beta_n=\frac{2}{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 +2},
\end{equation}
and you want to use the mean of the posterior as you Bayesian estimator, then (as you already wrote) you need to find $\alpha \beta$.

It is easy to see that
\begin{equation}
\alpha_n\beta_n =\frac{n+2}{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 +2} = \frac{1+\frac{2}{n}}{\left(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2\right) + \frac{2}{n}} 
\end{equation}

Using the [law of large numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers) and the distribution and independence assumption on $X_i$, it holds that
$$ \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 \to \frac{1}{\theta} \quad \text{ as } n \to \infty$$

Therefore $$ \alpha_n \beta_n \to \theta \quad \text{ as } n \to \infty$$ in probability (or almost surely, depending on whether you use the weak or the strong law of large numbers).

Therefore, the estimator is consistent.